# Pm2 авто рестарт процесса не работает при запуске через npm start

Tags: node.js, pm2

Я запускаю backend через команду

```
pm2 start npm --name backend -- run start
```

Процесс запускается успешно, но если backend падает, то restart процесса не происходит...

Если прокидывать скрипт на прямую, тогда restart работает

```
pm2 start server.js --name backend
```

Мне нужно запустить процесс pm2 именно через npm и auto reaload в случае падения приложения

Answer (score 0):

Возможно есть решение используя только Pm2, но, как вариант, можно сделать и так:
создать файл запуска, например `app.js` с таким кодом:

```
const child_process = require('child_process')

const webpack = child_process.exec('npm run dev', (err, stdout, stderr) => {
  console.log(err)
  console.log(stdout)
  console.log(stderr)
})
webpack.stdout.pipe(process.stdout)
```

запускать так `pm2 start app.js`

Comment: Попробовал - безуспешно, работает так же... Может есть какие-то другие способы? Не обязательно pm2, я пробовал с "Forever" с ним аналогичная история как и с pm2... я уже не знаю что делать...

Comment: а после команды `pm2 start`, Вы запускаете команду `pm2 save`?... хотя, наверное, не решит проблему

Comment: Использую, но это не помогает... неужели моя проблема не решаема? Я уже отчаялся и не знаю что делать